# cannot kill fbi process started from a python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, fbi

This python code runs fbi in an infinite loop even though there is a trap for ctrl-C

```
import os
var = 1
try:
    while var == 1:
        os.system("sleep 5; kill $(pgrep fbi); sudo fbi -a image1.jpg")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    kill $(pgrep fbi)
    pass
```

I hit ctrl-C, the screen blinks and image1 is back up.
Now I know python is behaving properly because this code exits with ctrl-C

```
import os
var = 1
x = 0
try:
    while var == 1:
        x += 1
        print x
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

and when I open another virtual console with alt-F2, login and try

```
sudo kill -9 fbi
```

of course the python process just restarts it. I have to kill the python process. The reason for doing this is to use fbi to display images in a python process that does image processing on a raspberry pi that is NOT running x windows, ubuntu, etc. It is console only.

Why doesn't fbi respect the keyboard interrupt?

Comment: Try re-raising the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception at the end of the `except:` suite.

Comment: `kill $(pgrep fbi)` is shell syntax, not Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill $(pgrep fbi)` is not Python syntax, you can't put it directly into the Python script. You need to execute it as a shell command, just like you did when you were starting up `fbi`.

```
import os
var = 1
try:
    while var == 1:
        os.system("sleep 5; sudo pkill fbi; sudo fbi -a image1.jpg")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.system("sudo pkill fbi")
```

Also, if you run `fbi` with `sudo`, you need to use `sudo` when killing it as well. An ordinary user can't kill a process being run by root.

It's better to use `pkill fbi` instead of `kill $(pgrep fbi)`. The latter will get an error if `pgrep` doesn't find any processes, because it will execute `kill` with no arguments.

Comment: well, that was a good catch on my syntax error but unfortunately, fbi is unkillable. (in fact i wanted to make the title of this post 'you can't kill fbi' but knew it would be flagged by some algo at a 3 letter agency). It seems fbi traps key presses (that's how it allows a user to advance through an image list) so the keyboard interrupt is never passed on back to the os.

Comment: Are you sure it's just `fbi`? What happens if you put `sleep 200` there? I suspect it's the subshell that's trapping keyboard interrupts.

Comment: yep, on my raspberry Pi 3 with the latest stretch lite, i am stuck in fbi 'hell'. cannot escape unless i kill the python process.